# Gaming console HDMI out to old DVI monitor with sound separated

Tags: audio, hdmi, dvi

Hi I have a gaming console which only outputs video and sound via HDMI port. I want to connect it to an old monitor I have, which takes DVI as input for video and has a 3.5 mm stereo headphone jack for sound.

Is there something that can split the HDMI source into DVI + headphone jack? Thanks.

Comment: Such devices do exist, but [product recommendations are off-topic on Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) so we won't be able to help you any further. Look for "HDMI to DVI with audio splitter".

Comment: @gronostaj No I guess you have answered my question already. I did not even know such device exists not to mention what it is called. Please go ahead and provide more details about what it is without suggesting one, then I can pick yours as the answer. Thanks.